# org.json.simple.JSONObject cannot be cast to org.json.JSONObject

Tags: android, json

When I run the following code...

```
  JSONObject jsonObject = null;
  JSONParser parser=new JSONParser(); // this needs the "json-simple" library

  try 
  {
        Object obj = parser.parse(responseBody);
        jsonObject=(JSONObject)obj;
  }
  catch(Exception ex)
  {
        Log.v("TEST","Exception1: " + ex.getMessage());
  }
```

...at runtime I see the following in my log output:

```
Exception1: org.json.simple.JSONObject cannot be cast to org.json.JSONObject
```

I don't understand why.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

You have imported the wrong class. Change

```
import org.json.JSONObject;
```

to

```
import org.json.simple.JSONObject;
```

Comment: Is there any way to cast that type if I want to use both the libraries?

Answer (score 4):

Change your code as:

```
  org.json.simple.JSONObject jsonObject = null;
  JSONParser parser=new JSONParser(); // this needs the "json-simple" library

  try 
  {
        Object obj = parser.parse(responseBody);
        jsonObject=(org.json.simple.JSONObject)obj;
  }
  catch(Exception ex)
  {
        Log.v("TEST","Exception1: " + ex.getMessage());
  }
```

or if you are using only `org.json.simple` library for parsing json string then just import `org.json.simple.*`  instead of `org.json.JSONObject`

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use an `org.json.JSONObject` you can do it by replacing this:

```
JSONObject jsonObject = null;
JSONParser parser=new JSONParser(); // this needs the "json-simple" library

try 
{
    Object obj = parser.parse(responseBody);
    jsonObject=(JSONObject)obj;
}
catch(Exception ex)
{
    Log.v("TEST","Exception1: " + ex.getMessage());
}
```

with:

```
JSONObject jsonObject = null;
JSONParser parser=new JSONParser(); // this needs the "json-simple" library

try 
{
    String obj = parser.parse(responseBody).toString(); //converting Object to String
    jsonObject = new JSONObject(obj); // org.json.JSONObject constructor accepts String as an argument
}
catch(Exception ex)
{
    Log.v("TEST","Exception1: " + ex.getMessage());
}
```

Comment: See "[Explaining entirely code-based answers](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/392712/128421)". While this might be technically correct it doesn't explain why it solves the problem or should be the selected answer. We should educate in addition to help solve the problem.