# impossible to parse jsonArray java

Tags: java, json, parsing

i have read lot of threads about this problem but not help me...

I have this json file

```
{
"list": [
    {
        "id": 1,
        "ipAdress": "123.456.789.123"
    }
]
}
```

and this code

```
public static void ipAdressByAHUIp(int id) throws IOException, ParseException {
    String ipAdressFile = "src\\main\\resources\\files\\AHU\\InServiceAHU.txt";
    JSONParser parser = new JSONParser();

    Object obj = parser.parse(new FileReader(ipAdressFile));
    JSONObject jsonObject = (JSONObject) obj;
    JSONArray msg = (JSONArray) jsonObject.get("list");

     for(int i = 0;i < msg.length();i++ ) {
         JSONObject jsonObj = msg.getJSONObject(i);

         int id2 = jsonObj.getInt("id");
         String value = jsonObj.getString("ipAdress");

         if (1 == id2) {
              //now 'value' is what you want
              System.out.println(value);
         }
     }  
}
```

i want to return ipAdress when id = 1...
But this error :

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: org.json.simple.JSONObject cannot be cast to org.json.JSONObject
```

i don't know why .... I have already search on internet..

my import :

```
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.simple.JSONObject;
import org.json.simple.parser.JSONParser;
import org.json.simple.parser.ParseException;
```

and if i change

```
import org.json.JSONObject;
```

to

```
import org.json.simple.JSONObject;
```

I have probleme here :

[IMAGE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7duvq.png)

Comment: Check your `import` statements. Your error message suggests you're mixing classes from two different JSON packages, ie. `org.json.simple`  and `org.json`.

Comment: If I query your exception, the first answer contains code that should work for you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14772764/org-json-simple-jsonobject-cannot-be-cast-to-org-json-jsonobject

Comment: my import : 

import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.simple.JSONObject;
import org.json.simple.parser.JSONParser;
import org.json.simple.parser.ParseException; -------- > maybe my problem is not import ?

Comment: Please add your `import` statements to your question. Maybe try changing `org.json.simple.JSONObject` to `org.json.JSONObject`

Comment: i have add in my question :)